# How to xss clean except html tag

Tags: php

I've been hunting around the net now for a few days trying to figure this out but getting conflicting answers.

Is there a library, class or function for PHP that securely sanitizes/encodes a string against XSS? It needs to be updated regularly to counter new attacks.

I have a few use cases:

**text** `<script>alert(111)</script>`

Comment: XSS is not really something that happens to "a string". It is a family of attack techniques that rely on getting unwanted scripts to run in the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

The most advanced library is http://htmlpurifier.org It allows you to add tags you want to allow.

Comment: I think you've done a better job of figuring out what he wants than I was able to do.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is sanitize text/data before using it.

```
<?php

$given_text = '<script>alert("you are hacked")</script>';

//before using it

$given_text = htmlspecialchars($given_text);

//now the text will be like this

&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;you are hacked&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;

?>
```

**Note :** And also cookies should not be accessible to scripts